# Building an ERD Diagram But the Results coming are very complicated Array of Structs,

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, lucee

I created an ERD Diagram but the results are coming as complex data, i am getting a very complicated set of array and structures,Looking for an advice how can i normalize it and show in a better way

[image]

even if `serialize`, i am not sure how can i build it

I tried `serializing` it, but even if i had serialized, how do i display it

possibly converted to JSON

```
    [
  {
    "COLS": [
      {
        "NAME": "authorid (int, not null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "firstname (varchar(50), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "lastname (varchar(50), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "sorted (int, null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "createdon (datetime, null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "modifiedby (char(50), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "objects (xml, null)"
      }
    ],
    "FKEYS": [],
    "NAME": "author",
    "LONGEST_STRING": 29
  },
  {
    "COLS": [
      {
        "NAME": "SectionID (int, not null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "SectionName (nchar(20), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "Createdby (datetime, null)"
      }
    ],
    "FKEYS": [],
    "NAME": "Sections",
    "LONGEST_STRING": 29
  },
  {
    "COLS": [
      {
        "NAME": "id (uniqueidentifier, null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "name (varchar(50), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "email (varchar(50), null)"
      }
    ],
    "FKEYS": [],
    "NAME": "testtable",
    "LONGEST_STRING": 27
  },
  {
    "COLS": [
      {
        "NAME": "id (int, not null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "maths (varchar(50), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "science (varchar(50), null)"
      }
    ],
    "FKEYS": [],
    "NAME": "createdable",
    "LONGEST_STRING": 27
  },
  {
    "COLS": [
      {
        "NAME": "aid (int, not null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "createdon (datetime, null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "exacttime (timestamp, null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "sorted (int, null)"
      }
    ],
    "FKEYS": [],
    "NAME": "author_dates",
    "LONGEST_STRING": 27
  },
  {
    "COLS": [
      {
        "NAME": "id (int, not null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "name (varchar(100), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "email (varchar(255), null)"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "phonenumber (int, null)"
      }
    ],
    "FKEYS": [],
    "NAME": "updates",
    "LONGEST_STRING": 26
  }
]
```

Comment: i solved it with converting to query, the above question, but what about this one, how to with this one, i think it need tons of loops

Comment: First, what you are trying to achieve is not clear.  Second, what did you do to get the data being displayed in your question.

Comment: i converted it to JSON but as i said i am still uncertain how should i show it

Comment: What did you have that you converted to json?

Comment: above i used serializejson to do t, now i am looking some js libraries which converts the json to erd diagram format

Comment: With complex data, especially those representing objects or entities, there is often a limit to how far you can simplify the structure. That is certainly the case with your object. You're right that the array-of-structs and JSON representations look complex. Nevertheless they're accurate and efficient. Converting to a query will be inefficient or inaccurate. That is because the sets of column names are different. The best solution is to either look for a tool that converts JSON (schema) to ERD or UML or, simply, to manually contruct the ERDs.

Comment: is there any tool what does json to uml or erd